# Run a program on a remote computer after a SQL job has completed

Tags: sql-server-2012, sql-server-agent, jobs

We have a SQL Agent Job that performs a few tasks every night (schedulled to run using SQL Agent). The database server is SQL 2012 if that makes a difference.

We have another process (a .net program) that needs to run on a different server **after** the job has finished on each server. The program cannot be installed on the database server.

Is there a way to get a SQL Agent Job to run a program on another computer after it has finished, or is there an easy way to indicate to a program on another computer that the job has finished?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using

- PSEXEC from sysinternals.
- powershell using remoting functionality. (https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7703.powershell-running-executables.aspx
  )

you cam have a batch file call your program and can use xp_cmdshell (if allowed) or operating system task in SQL agent job to run the job locally. This job can be called using linked server or powershell after the main step in the original job is completed.